# SQL Server query to extract data from SOAP 1.1 from two different nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, soap

I'm able to extract data from the following XML using SQL Server:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetBatchResponse xmlns="https://webservices.aba.com/">
   <web:GetBatchResult xmlns:web="https://webservices.aba.com/">
    <web:Loco>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Sam</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.10</web:Height>
        <web:Age>26</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
      </web:Pos>
      <web:Address />
      <web:EmpUnit>21</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Emma</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.7</web:Height>
        <web:Age>21</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Prince</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.11</web:Height>
        <web:Age>25</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Smith</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.6</web:Height>
        <web:Age>24</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
      </web:Pos>
      <web:Address />
      <web:EmpUnit>17</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
    </web:Loco>
    <web:EndTimeUTC xsi:nil="true" />
   </web:GetBatchResult>
  </GetBatchResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Stored the above XML in a **TestXML** table, column **XMLPayload** (Column DataType: XML)

I'm using the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE testResult (Name VARCHAR(10), Height FLOAT, Age INT, SALARY BIGINT, EmpUnit INT, EmpOrg VARCHAR(10))

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
INSERT INTO testResult
SELECT
 reponse.data.value('*.Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS Name,
 reponse.data.value('*.Height/text())[1]','FLOAT') AS Height,
 reponse.data.value('*.Age/text())[1]','INT') AS Age,
 reponse.data.value('*.Salary/text())[1]','BIGINT)') AS Salary,
 NULL AS EmpUnit,
 NULL AS EmpOrg
FROM testXML t
CROSS APPLY XMLPayload.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:GetBatchResponse/*:GetBatchResult/*:Loco/*:LocoType/*:Pos/*:PosType') AS response(data)
```

Using the above query, I was able to get Name, Height, Age & Salary. I wasn't able to fetch the data for EmpUnit and EmpOrg, that's why I used NULL in the above query.

I need to get the values for EmpUnit & EmpOrg as well. Like, EmpUnit & EmpOrg is going to have values for the 1st and last row only (21,XE & 17, XE), and for the other rows, EmpUnit & EmpOrg is going to be null.

Need some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, don't tag MySQL as well; it;s a completely different product.

Comment: Also, `;` doesn't go at the start of statement that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated, it goes at the end of all your statements. `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginningator", and not terminating your statements properly is deprecated. Get in the habit of doing it correctly now.

Comment: Your XML, however, is not valid. For example on line 12 you open the node `web:Age`, but close it as just `Age`. Also, on line 48 you close the node `web:GetBatchReult` but it was opened as `GetBatchReult`. To parse XML in SQL Server, it needs to be valid XML.

Comment: @Larnu, I was typing the XML to produce an example to showcase over here. So, the errors you have mentioned, are typing mistakes. MY BAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we *assume* your XML is valid, which I've corrected in the below, you can do this.

Firstly, the reason yours isn't working is because you're going to the `Pos/PosType` node in your `nodes` call, but `EmpUnit` is in the `LocoType` node.

Instead, use 2 `nodes` calls. Also, I define your namespaces explicitly in both the `XMLNAMESPACES` and XML `nodes`/`value` calls:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetBatchResponse xmlns="https://webservices.aba.com/">
   <web:GetBatchReult xmlns:web="https://webservices.aba.com/">
    <web:Loco>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Sam</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.10</web:Height>
        <web:Age>26</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
      </web:Pos>
      <web:Address />
      <web:EmpUnit>21</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Emma</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.7</web:Height>
        <web:Age>21</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Prince</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.11</web:Height>
        <web:Age>25</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
       <web:PosType>
        <web:Name>Smith</web:Name>
        <web:Height>5.6</web:Height>
        <web:Age>24</web:Age>
        <web:Salary />
       </web:PosType>
      </web:Pos>
      <web:Address />
      <web:EmpUnit>17</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
    </web:Loco>
    <web:EndTimeUTC xsi:nil="true" />
   </web:GetBatchReult>
  </GetBatchResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
--Seems odd that the default namespace and the "web" namespace have the same value.
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'https://webservices.aba.com/', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap, 'https://webservices.aba.com/' AS web)
SELECT L.LT.value('(./web:EmpUnit/text())[1]','int') AS EmpUnit,
       L.LT.value('(./web:EmpOrg/text())[1]','char(2)') AS EmpOrg,
       P.PT.value('(./web:Name/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS Name,
       P.PT.value('(./web:Height/text())[1]','decimal(5,2)') AS Height, --Float name no sense for a precise value
       P.PT.value('(./web:Age/text())[1]','int') AS Age,
       P.PT.value('(./web:Salary/text())[1]','bigint') AS Salary --Can someone really be paid over 2billion?
FROM @XML.nodes('soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetBatchResponse/web:GetBatchReult/web:Loco/web:LocoType') L(LT)
     CROSS APPLY L.LT.nodes('web:Pos/web:PosType')P(PT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working. But my question is, the for the 1st row the EmpUnit is coming as 21 & EmpOrg as XE, and for rest of the rows the EmpUnit & EmpOrgare coming as 21 & XE respectively. Don't you think, only the last row should have 21 & XE as EmpUnit & EmpOrg, & other rows except the 1st should have Nulls? I'm not very familiar with SOAP/XML.

Comment: Not when i look at your data, no @AritraSarkar . The last 3 rows all belong to the same  `LocoType` node, so all share the same value for `EmpUnit` and `EmpOrg` which belongs to said node.