# Query to extract SOAP 1.1 response from 4 different nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, soap

I have the below XML:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetBatchResponse xmlns="https://webservices.aba.com/">
   <web:GetBatchResult xmlns:web="https://webservices.aba.com/">
    <web:Loco>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos />
      <web:Ref />
      <web:Episode>
       <web:EpisodeType>
        <web:EpisodeId>1</web:EpisodeId>
        <web:StartTime>2021-02-01T01:41:58</web:StartTime>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
         <web:Name>Sam</web:Name>
         <web:Height>5.10</web:Height>
         <web:Age>26</web:Age>
         <web:Salary />
        </web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
         <web:Grade>C</web:Grade>
         <web:Salary>500</web:Salary>
        </web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
       </web:EpisodeType>
      </web:Episode>
      <web:EmpUnit>21</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos />
      <web:Ref />
      <web:Episode>
       <web:EpisodeType>
        <web:EpisodeId>2</web:EpisodeId>
        <web:StartTime>2021-02-02T01:41:58</web:StartTime>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
         <web:Name>Emma</web:Name>
         <web:Height>5.5</web:Height>
         <web:Age>23</web:Age>
         <web:Salary />
        </web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
         <web:Grade>B</web:Grade>
         <web:Salary>550</web:Salary>
        </web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
       </web:EpisodeType>
      </web:Episode>
      <web:EmpUnit>17</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
    </web:Loco>
    <web:EndTimeUTC xsi:nil="true" />
   </web:GetBatchResult>
  </GetBatchResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is not a valid xml, just a replica created by me. Please ignore any typing mistakes, if found.

I'm able to extract the data from the 1st and the last node, i.e., I'm able to get EpisodeId, StartTime, EmpUnit and EmpOrg using the below query:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetBatchResponse xmlns="https://webservices.aba.com/">
   <web:GetBatchResult xmlns:web="https://webservices.aba.com/">
    <web:Loco>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos />
      <web:Ref />
      <web:Episode>
       <web:EpisodeType>
        <web:EpisodeId>1</web:EpisodeId>
        <web:StartTime>2021-02-01T01:41:58</web:StartTime>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
         <web:Name>Sam</web:Name>
         <web:Height>5.10</web:Height>
         <web:Age>26</web:Age>
         <web:Salary />
        </web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
         <web:Grade>C</web:Grade>
         <web:Salary>500</web:Salary>
        </web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
       </web:EpisodeType>
      </web:Episode>
      <web:EmpUnit>21</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
     <web:LocoType>
      <web:Errors />
      <web:Pos />
      <web:Ref />
      <web:Episode>
       <web:EpisodeType>
        <web:EpisodeId>2</web:EpisodeId>
        <web:StartTime>2021-02-02T01:41:58</web:StartTime>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
         <web:Name>Emma</web:Name>
         <web:Height>5.5</web:Height>
         <web:Age>23</web:Age>
         <web:Salary />
        </web:EpisodeDataAtStart>
        <web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
         <web:Grade>B</web:Grade>
         <web:Salary>550</web:Salary>
        </web:EpisodeDataAtEnd>
       </web:EpisodeType>
      </web:Episode>
      <web:EmpUnit>17</web:EmpUnit>
      <web:EmpOrg>XE</web:EmpOrg>
     </web:LocoType>
    </web:Loco>
    <web:EndTimeUTC xsi:nil="true" />
   </web:GetBatchResult>
  </GetBatchResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'https://webservices.aba.com/', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap, 'https://webservices.aba.com/' AS web)
SELECT 
       P.PT.value('(./web:EpisodeId/text())[1]','INT') AS INT,
       P.PT.value('(./web:StartTime/text())[1]','DATETIME') AS StartTime,
       L.LT.value('(./web:EmpUnit/text())[1]','int') AS EmpUnit,
       L.LT.value('(./web:EmpOrg/text())[1]','char(2)') AS EmpOrg
FROM @XML.nodes('soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetBatchResponse/web:GetBatchReult/web:Loco/web:LocoType') L(LT)
     CROSS APPLY L.LT.nodes('web:Episode/web:EpisodeType')P(PT);
```

I also need the values for Name, Height, Age, SalaryAtStart, Grade and SalaryAtEnd

Need some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply what you learned from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66257245/2029983) and you should be able to easily do this.

Comment: In xmlnamespaces you define both `DEFAULT 'https://webservices.aba.com/'` and `'https://webservices.aba.com/' AS web` but they're the same namespace URI so you only need one. Delete `'https://webservices.aba.com/' AS web` and all of the `web:` prefixes in your query. Also `/web:GetBatchReult/` appears to be a typo and should be `/GetBatchResult/` (with an `s` in `Result`) after deleting the `web:` prefix.

Comment: `P.PT.value('(web:EpisodeDataAtStart/web:Name/text())[1]'...` works?

Comment: hi @Charlieface, Yes, it works. But for a long XML, everything's messing up.

Comment: "everything's messing up." means what exactly? You need to explain why answers to previous questions have not worked.

Comment: No, it's working. everything was messing up as SQL Server was retaining stuffs from previous execution in its metadata. It's working now. Thanks a lot